# drive.properties for loop with google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have two functions in a google sheet that are meant to loop through a single column containing the file IDs of files in google drive, issuing a Properties.get to retrieve a single property "LastReview" for each document and paste all of the LastReview times in the next available column.

I'm having trouble getting the loop in "loopForMetadata" to work. I want it to acquire a list of all the LastReview times associated with each fileID and then post that to the next available column so that all of the LastReview times align with the fileIDs.

```
function getProperty(fileId) {
    var propertyKey = 'LastReview'
    var fileId = '1UaQkJU8r1kE9sxpFg6OD8aOuUCoRnSpB9Agg_R9HJ3s'
    var response = JSON.stringify(Drive.Properties.get(fileId, 'LastReview', { visibility: 'PUBLIC' }).value);
    var key = "value";
    var resposeNoQuote = response.replace(/\"/g, "")
    Logger.log(resposeNoQuote);

}

function loopForMetadata() {

    var columnNeeded, data, lastColumn, sh;

    sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();

    data = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();//Get 2D array of all values in row one
    data = data[0];//Get the first and only inner array

    columnNeeded = data.indexOf('ID') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
    var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
    var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
    var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2, columnNeeded, lastRow - 1, 1);
    // Get array of values in the search Range
    var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
    // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
    // background color.
    var resultValues = []
    for (i = 0; i < rangeValues.length; i++) {
        resultValues.push(getProperty(rangeValues[i]));
        Utilities.sleep(10);


    }
    Logger.log(resultValues);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values using the key of `LastReview` in the property from the files of `fileId`.
- You want to put the retrieved values to the same row of `fileId` in the next available column.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification point:

- In your script,

  - `getProperty()` doesn't return the values.
  - `resultValues` is not put to the Spreadsheet.
  - When you want to retrieve the value of the key `LastReview`, `Drive.Properties.get(fileId, 'LastReview', { visibility: 'PUBLIC' }).value` directly returns the value.
- As an important point, when the file of `fileId` has not property of the key `LastReview`, it seems that `Drive.Properties.get()` occurs an error. So in this modification, as a simple workaround, I used the try catch.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function loopForMetadata() {
  var columnNeeded, data, lastColumn, sh;
  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();
  data = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();//Get 2D array of all values in row one
  data = data[0];//Get the first and only inner array
  columnNeeded = data.indexOf('ID') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2, columnNeeded, lastRow - 1, 1);
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  var resultValues = []
  
  // I modified below script.
  for (i = 0; i < rangeValues.length; i++) {
    var fileId = rangeValues[i];
    var value = "";
    try {
      value = Drive.Properties.get(fileId, 'LastReview', { visibility: 'PUBLIC' }).value;
    } catch(e) {}
    resultValues.push([value]);
//    Utilities.sleep(10);  // I'm not sure whether this is required.
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, lastColumn + 1, resultValues.length, 1).setValues(resultValues);
  Logger.log(resultValues);
};
```

#### Note:

- Please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, again.

#### Reference:

- [Properties: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/properties/get)

Comment: by jove, you've done it! Your response is positively exceptional! Thank you

Comment: @W.Lyman Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.